# Change various elements style.left and top with script?

Tags: javascript

I have this loop that produces many elements with different positions:

```
if ( $row['Type'] == "house") { ?>
    <div class="itemW" style="margin-left: <?=$row['X']?>px; margin-top: <?=$row['Y']?>px;">
    Item
   </div> <? 
}
```

I need to change all the divs left position, I'm trying this:

```
 var items = document.getElementsByClassName("itemW");
 items[0].style.left = land.width() / items[0].style.left * 100;
```

The problem is that `items[0].style.left` doesn't get the position of the first div. Also I don't know how to do it with all the divs.

Comment: btw `land.width()` can be used to obtain the screen width and `land.height()` to obtain the height since It's a div with 100% width and 100% height.

Comment: Can you use jQuery?  It will make this kind of operation much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all elements with a particular class name with

```
document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
```

for [anything but IE < 9 at least](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t11) :P

Then it's just a matter of looping through them like so

```
var meh = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
for (var i = 0; i < meh.length; i++)
    meh[i].style.left = land.width() / items[0].style.left * 100 + "px"; // "px" is very important.
                                                                         // also this will only work
                                                                         // if you have first set the
                                                                         // element's style attribute.
```

Comment: how do I modify all their styles after selecting them? if you tell me how to give them all a 100px left position I can figure out the rest.

Comment: @Liso22 see my edit.  make sure you set the element's style to something `style="left:0px; top:0px;"` etc.

Comment: +1 for: "px" is very important **AND** also this will only work if you have **first set the element's style attribute**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with jQuery:

```
$('.itemW').each(function () {
    var item = $(this);
    var pos = item.position();

    item.css('left', (item.width() / pos.left * 100) + 'px');
    item.css('top', (item.height() / pos.top * 100) + 'px');
});
```